# android - Difference between android:name and android:label

Tags: android, android-manifest

I am flutter developer and some Android settings confuses me.

What is the difference between `android:label` and `android:name` in `AndroidManifest.xml`??

```
<application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="flutterapp2"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The

```
android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
```

is a default to a Flutter application & you should NOT edit this anyway (unless you created a class that extends FlutterApplication class).

The `android:label` is to define your app name, which is display in the installed application list.

If you want to change the app name in home screen, check `android:label` inside the `<activity />` tag

For more information, check out the official documentation:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element

> `android:name`
>   The fully qualified name of an Application subclass
>   implemented for the application. When the application process is
>   started, this class is instantiated before any of the application's
>   components. The subclass is optional; most applications won't need
>   one. In the absence of a subclass, Android uses an instance of the
>   base Application class.
>
> `android:label`
>   A user-readable label for the application as a whole, and a default
>   label for each of the application's components. See the individual
>   label attributes for , , ,
>   , and  elements. The label should be set as a
>   reference to a string resource, so that it can be localized like other
>   strings in the user interface. However, as a convenience while you're
>   developing the application, it can also be set as a raw string.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Pretty counterintuitive names though. `android:name` is a fqn class!

Answer (score 3):

**android:name** this is a class which will wxecute first time (this is not your app name ,this is a functional thing)
and
**android:label** this is name of app shown on icon which represent the app name

Answer (score 1):

According to https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element

> `android:name`
>
> The fully qualified name of an Application subclass implemented for the application. When the application process is started, this
>   class is instantiated before any of the application's components.
>
> The subclass is optional; most applications won't need one. In the absence of a subclass, Android uses an instance of the base
>   Application class.
>
> `android:label`
>
> A user-readable label for the application as a whole, and a default label for each of the application's components. See the
>   individual label attributes for , ,
>   , , and  elements.
>
> The label should be set as a reference to a string resource, so that it can be localized like other strings in the user interface.
>   However, as a convenience while you're developing the application, it
>   can also be set as a raw string.

Answer (score 0):

The android documentation states the following and you may find the list of attributes [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#label)

> android:name
>   The fully qualified name of an Application subclass implemented for the application. When the application process is started, this class is instantiated before any of the application's components.
>   The subclass is optional; most applications won't need one. In the absence of a subclass, Android uses an instance of the base Application class.
>
> android:label
>   A user-readable label for the application as a whole, and a default label for each of the application's components. See the individual label attributes for , , , , and  elements.
>   The label should be set as a reference to a string resource, so that it can be localized like other strings in the user interface. However, as a convenience while you're developing the application, it can also be set as a raw string.

Answer (score -1):

android name is the name of the package that you are defining for that project and android label is the default name for your application